# Mongodb nodejs query not working even though it should

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm performing the following query:

```
   dateBeforeTenDays.setDate(dateBeforeTenDays.getDate() - 10);

 database.collection('eatSmart.gatro-membership-payments').countDocuments({}, function (err, totalCount) {
    if (err) {
        response = { "error": true, "message": "Error fetching data" }
    }

    var query = {$and: [{dueDate: {$lte: today}}, {dueDate: {$gte: dateBeforeTenDays}}, {alertSend: {$ne: true}}]};
    database.collection('gatro-membership-payments').find(query).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        docs.forEach(function(item){
            //getFirebaseData(item);
        });
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work and i dont know why because in my oppinion it should. Here is the dataset it should print but didn't

```
[ { _id: 'QcVkZQhXS4bcpmv0rUpanoEyRhp2',
invoiceCreated: false,
paid: 2020-10-17T22:45:23.147Z,
alertSend: false,
dueDate: 2022-10-06T22:45:23.147Z,
years: 2 } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Mongoose aggregates your query the way you expect.

Instead of

```
var query = {$and: [{dueDate: {$lte: today}}, {dueDate: {$gte: dateBeforeTenDays}}, {alertSend: {$ne: true}}]};
```

You should pass the two operators in the same object

```
var query = {$and: [{dueDate: {$lte: today, $gte: dateBeforeTenDays}}, {alertSend: {$ne: true}}]};
```

Reference here
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately its getting no data because the $lte today part is the problem but i dont know why